# Whitespace in command alias

Tags: command-line, bash, execute-command

For example, I want to make a command `good night` and this would look something like `alias good night="many many many commands here"`. I tried this but, whitespace is not allowed. Is there any way I could accomplish this?

Comment: Try to use good_night, or assign an alias to good, and an alias to night, and see what happens. I think it could work.

Comment: i just want to know if its possible i just want white space sir

Comment: You could make a script or Bash function that is named `good`, which reads its arguments, requires the first one to be "night" and then executes the commands you want.

Comment: Aliases are deprecated. Use a function instead.

Comment: @ujwaldhakal Why do you need the whitespace? Why not `goodnight`?

Comment: @wjandrea ours is not to question but to answer ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Lol, I know, but this feels like an XY problem.

Comment: @wjandrea see what question wants to explain.. making whitespace in command alias

Comment: @ujwaldhakal I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 10):

This function should get you started:

```
good () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Perhaps you meant 'good night'?"
    else
        if [ "$1" = "night" ]; then
            echo "GOOD"
            echo "NIGHT"
            echo "good"
            echo "night"
            echo "etc"
        else
            echo "ERROR: strange time detected: $1"
        fi
    fi
}
```

Save it as, for example, `good.sh`, then `source` it:

```
. good.sh
```

`good night` now will execute various commands (replace the `echo` statements with whatever you want).

Comment: You can add the line that sources your script to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file so that the function will be available in every Bash session.

Comment: Or put the function itself in the bashrc, which may be more convenient.

Comment: You could simplify the logic a bit by removing the `if [ -z "$1" ]` statement. It's not needed.