# How to share files/folders between two different Ubuntu computers and are on different network?

Tags: server, remote-desktop, file-sharing, shared-folders

I want to share the folders between my laptop and local desktop. Both are connected to WiFi and ethernet respectively. How do I share the folders between these two?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If computers are connected to different networks, this can be achieved using [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/linux). It enables computers to see each other as if they were in the same network. It can be used with very nice front-end called [Haguichi](https://www.haguichi.net).

[image]

**If your computers are connected to the same local network start from here.**

Now you need to share files somehow. Fortunately, Ubuntu makes it really easy. Just right-click any directory and pick `Local Network Share`.
Window like this one should pop up:

[image]

Then configure your share and click `Create Share`.

**On the other PC**

Open Nautilus, click `Connect to Server` on the left menu. Another dialog should pop up:

[image]

Type in `smb://[ip address of the other computer here]` and click `Connect`.

If you use Hamachi, you will need to provide host's IP as seen by Hamachi. Either use `hamachi list` command or right-click other computer in Haguichi and select `Copy IPv4 Address`.

And that's it!

Answer (score 6):

If you are capable to establish [SSH connection](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) between these two computers, you can use `sshfs` to mount a remote folder (even entire filesystem, if you have right permissions).

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y sshfs
```

For example, if you are using [key authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys), the mounting command looks like:

```
sshfs username@hostname_or_ip:/path/to/remote-folder/ /path/to/local-folder/ -p 2222 -o IdentityFile=/path/to/ssh-key/id_rsa
```

- `-p 2222` you can omit this option, if you are using the default ssh port `22`;
- `-o IdentityFile=/path/to/ssh-key/id_rsa` you can omit this option, if yours key is placed in the default location (`~/.ssh`), or if you using `~/.ssh/config` file;
- `username@hostname_or_ip` you can replace this entry with its equivalent *short name*, if you using `~/.ssh/config` file;
- use `sudo umount /path/to/local-folder/` to unmount;
- for more details check: `sshfs -h` or [its man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sshfs.1.html).

---

So, if the `~/.ssh/config` file looks like:

```
Host rh1
    HostName 79.11.134.121
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remote-host-1/id_rsa
    User spas
    Port 22

Host rh2
    HostName 193.164.5.50
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remote-host-2/id_rsa
    User spas
    Port 2222
```

The mounting command will looks more simple:

```
$ sshfs rh1:/path/to/remote-folder/ /path/to/local-folder/
```

---

Once `sshfs` mounting works, you can:

- create custom by [script file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118312/how-can-i-create-a-custom-terminal-command-to-run-a-script), [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) or [funcion](https://askubuntu.com/a/871120/566421) for fast mounting;
- create [fstab entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710149/how-to-convert-sshfs-command-to-fstab-entry) for permanent mounting (also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sshfs) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=975107));
- or create pure `~/.bashrc` entry, which could be enough for particular cases.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to use an **online sync with a local client**, which has the additional benefit of storing your data in the cloud. This is useful for instance if you have a PC at home and one at work/study, or in the extreme case that both of your computers fail.

I have experience with two clouds, which are very good: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/en/install-linux) and [Mega](https://mega.nz/#sync). There are [plenty more](http://alternativeto.net/software/mega/?platform=linux).

**To share folders**

- Install the client **in both computers** (see links above). Both create a menu entry. (Dropbox seems to have a bug relating its icon. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/737615/308164) to fix).
- Open the client in the computer which has the original folder and then create the sync. For example, in Megasync, right-click on the panel icon and select settings. Then, go to Sync tab, and select Add. Choose the *local* folder to share, and create a folder in your cloud. You should get something like this:

[image]

When you press OK, the files will start to be uploaded to Mega. The process is more or less similar with Dropbox. More details at the bottom of the post.

- Once the upload is complete, open the client in the other computer, and create a sync. Now, select the folder in the cloud, and a new, empty folder as *local* destination. The client will understand and start downloading the data in the cloud to your new folder.

That's it. Your two folders are in sync and secure in the cloud.

---

As I said, there are many sync clients. I prefer Mega because:

- it gives 50GB for free (Dropbox only gives 2GB)
- it is cheaper than Dropbox (if you go Pro)
- you can sync anywhere (e.g. `~/Music`); Dropbox sync only the content inside a "Dropbox" folder (e.g. `~/Dropbox/Music`), which is annoying.
- you can have many folders synchronized (`~/Music`, `~/Pics/My_puppy`, `~/.q3a`); Dropbox only allows for stuff inside the same "Dropbox" folder.

The only problem I see is that Mega can go bust at any time (because of copyright issues). It happened to Megaupload before. Dropbox might me more secure.