# Change directory to target of move operation

Tags: command-line, mv

Occasionally, I have edited some file and want to move it to a different folder. (Typically: to a Dropbox folder, where I did not want to work to avoid giving the other owners of the folder constant updates.) I do this, for example, with

```
mv file.pdf ../../../Dropbox/sharedfolder/subdirectory/file.pdf
```

Afterwards, I often find myself wanting to change directory to the target directory of my previous move operation. I find myself hitting the up arrow, deleting the final `file.pdf`, holding left, deleting `mv file.pdf` and replacing it with `cd`.

Is there a faster, smarter way to do this? Is there a "move file and then change directory to" command, or a shortcut for the last used directory, or something like that?

Comment: if you hold CTRL+Left, it will go left by word which is faster

Comment: Side comment, not an answer to your shell question: I typically just pause Dropbox whilst editing. It also ensures no other files get changed "under my feet".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using bash, then its history interaction has just the shortcut for this. The [word designator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators) for the last argument of the previous command:

> `!!:$`
>   designates the last argument of the preceding command. This may be
>   shortened to `!$`.

Combined with [a modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) to remove the last pathname component:

After the optional word designator, you can add a sequence of one or more of the [valid modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifiers.html#Modifiers), each preceded by a ‘:’.

> `h`
>    Remove a trailing pathname component, leaving only the head.

So:

```
$ echo /ab/c/d
/ab/c/d
$ echo !$:h
echo /ab/c
/ab/c
```

---

The same shortcut can also be used with zsh.

Comment: This is so cool.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not changing the filename, you can omit it and mv will add it automatically; this is especially useful when moving multiple files:

```
mv file.pdf ../../../Dropbox/sharedfolder/subdirectory/

mv *.pdf ../../../Dropbox/sharedfolder/subdirectory/
```

With the directory as the last argument, you can use `!!:$` or `!$` as muru's answer describes.
If you're using bash with the usual defaults, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+**<kbd>.</kbd>** instead.
(This is the readline `insert-last-argument` command; `bind -p` will list all your current bindings.)

Comment: note that omitting the destination filename can silently overwrite the destination file if it already existis

Comment: `mv` always overwrites destination files silently unless you specify the options `-i`/`--interactive` or `-n`/`--no-clobber`. That's why I have `alias mv='mv -i' cp='cp -i'` in my `.bashrc`.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to create your own command dedicated for this purpose. This can be done via [function](https://askubuntu.com/a/871120/566421) which could looks like:

```
$ function mv-special { mv $1 $2; cd $(dirname $(echo $2-)); }
```

<sup>Where: **(1)** `mv-special` is the function name; **(2)** the variables `$1` and `$2` are arguments in the function who will be used by the commands `mv` and `cd`; **(3)** `$(echo $2-)` adds a wildcat character to the end of the string in var `$2`, and fixes the behaviour of [`dirname`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=80207) if the variable `$2` contains only path; **(4)** `$(dirname $(echo $2-))` will filter only the path from `$2`.</sup>

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362952/6543935) the function could looks like:

```
$ function mv-special { mv $1 $2; cd ${2%/*}; }
```

<sup>Where: `${2%/*}` will filter only the path from `$2`.</sup>

To be available as a command this function must be [exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export):

```
$ export -f mv-special
```

Usage:

```
$ mv-special file.pdf ../../../Dropbox/sharedfolder/subdirectory/file.pdf
```

or:

```
$ mv-special file.pdf ../../../Dropbox/sharedfolder/subdirectory/
```

Please pay attention to that - for both variants - the second argument (`$2`) must finishes with filename or slash (`/`).

To be our new command permanently available, the definition of the function and the export command must be appended to `~/.bashrc`:

```
# My custom 'mv-special' command:
function mv-special { mv $1 $2; cd $(dirname $(echo $2-)); }
export -f mv-special
```

or:

```
# My custom 'mv-special' command:
function mv-special { mv $1 $2; cd ${2%/*}; }
export -f mv-special
```

[image]

---

Custom command can be made and via executable script file which is placed in `~/bin` or in `/usr/sbin`: [How can I create a custom terminal command (to run a script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118312/how-can-i-create-a-custom-terminal-command-to-run-a-script) But to be honest, I was faced a [trouble](https://www.google.bg/search?q=cd%20command%20and%20variables%20in%20script&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBG704BG704&oq=cd%20command%20and%20variables%20in%20script&aqs=chrome..69i57.12457j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with the behaviour of `cd` in this scenario.